# How to write one sign several times with existing function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Does this function already exist in Python3.4?

```
def repeat (number):
    str=""
    for i in range(number):
        str+="*"
    return(str)
```

Comment: Sort of: `return "*" * number`

Answer (score 5):

You can use simple String operations to achieve this.

```
def repeat(number):
    return "*" * number
```

or simply

```
print("*" * number)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of providing alternate answers, and as a demonstration of list comprehensions and the powerful `str.join(list)`, this also absolutely works:

```
def repeat(number):
    return "".join(["*" for x in range(number)])
```